# I want To Show Login screen Only once in IOS

Tags: ios

I had searched whole internet but not getting satisfiable Answer I want to show Login Screen Only Once after user Succesfull Login,
After LoginViewcontroller I have MainViewcontroller and I want To show that viewcontroller as long as user not logout.After Logout user againt go to login scReen from side menu and signInviewcontroller is my rootviewcontroller too.
So Do I have To write a Code in applicationWill terminate or application didbecomeActive or something else plese help...

currently i'm using this code below in AppDelegate but its not working..

```
if ([KnsUserDefault boolForKey:@"LoggedIn"])  {
    [KnsUserDefault setBool:YES forKey:@"LoggedIn"];
    [self.window addSubview:[self.mainVc view]];

    SignInVViewController *signVc = [[SignInVViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignInViewController" bundle:nil];
    signVc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self.mainVc presentViewController:signVc animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [self.window addSubview:[self.mainVc view]];
}
```

please help

Comment: we don't add subview to a `UIWindow` instance, horrible practice.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (![KnsUserDefault boolForKey:@"LoggedIn"]) {
```

It should work...

Comment: Its not working ..I'm also setting                 [saveDriverDefaultData setBool:YES forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];  in signInviewcontroller

Comment: Well, now you have to delete your app as you already set the key to YES once

Comment: Can You Explain setBool foKey in nsuserdeafualt

Comment: The UserDefault is a persistent storage space. If you already set YES, it will be YES until you overwrite the value or you delete the app (in this case the key doesn't exist and objc return NO, always)

Comment: Thnxx For Explanation Now I will delete and re run  my app thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Mohammed in your AppDelegate.m do like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
    Bool isLoggedIn = [KnsUserDefault boolForKey:@"LoggedIn"]
    if (isLoggedIn) 
    {
         [KnsUserDefault setBool:YES forKey:@"LoggedIn"];
          self.window.rootViewController = self.mainVC;
    }
    else
    {
         [KnsUserDefault setBool:NO forKey:@"LoggedIn"];
         SignInVViewController *signVc = [[SignInVViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignInViewController" bundle:nil];
         self.window.rootViewController = signVc;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thnxx Ismail,But I'm I have to do this NSUserdefault I can't use Nsnotification

Comment: The notification is not neccessary when you open the app it's for if you log out or your login sessoin expieres in the middle of the execution. You can simply remove the 4 lines of the notification and set  the userDefaults instead. the main part is how to set the view controller as your root view controller. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @MohammedHussain Please see my updated answer. Hope it help. If you have any question please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Ok ismail I'll try Give me Your Email ID

Comment: ismaill.hassanein@gmail.com